# How to let horizontal progress bar stay at the top of toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

### Action Bar

Previously, when using Action Bar, it is very simple to have horizontal progress bar at the top of action bar. By having code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
```

We can have

[image]

---

### Toolbar

Now, I wish to achieve the same look and feel by using AppCompat `Toolbar`. Without adding horizontal progress bar, my toolbar looks this way

[image]

After adding horizontal progress bar via the following layout.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    <!-- android:elevation="4dp" is used due to http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android- -->

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:max="100" android:progress="45"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

However, this is what I get

[image]

1. The horizontal progress bar is not at the top of toolbar, although I do specific `top` through `layout_gravity` and `gravity`.
2. Toolbar title text is gone.

I was wondering, is there anything I had missed?

Comment: You may consider choosing a valid answer or explain your problem if it's not solved already ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a vertical LinearLayout as a root instead:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <ProgressBar />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />

</LinearLayout>
```

Or as @CheokYanCheng said in the comment, you may want to use a `FrameLayout` to avoid the pushing effect.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:gravity="top"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />

    <ProgressBar />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be a LinearLayout, it can be a RelativeLayout or anything you want.

Comment: Yes of course, but it was the first simple thing that came to my mind ;)

Comment: I think FrameLayout should be used instead, to avoid progress bar from "pushing down" toolbar.